# React Native - flex: 1 not working for ios when keyboard opens

Tags: react-native

I have `View` with style `flex: 1` which contains an image and textbox that are centered on the screen. In android, the view shrinks when the textbox is focused and the keyboard is opened. However, in ios, the size of the view stays the same and the keyboard covers the content.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {  render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.box}/>        
  </View>
);  }}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
     flex: 1,
     justifyContent: 'center',
     paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
     backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
     padding: 8,
  },
  box: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'red'
 },
});
```

Created a sample code as above and tested in snack. In the above code, the textbox is not centered when keyboard opened for ios.

https://snack.expo.io/H1YO-qzpr

Comment: can you share an expo link where we can check?

Comment: Added expo link.

Comment: what is the error? couldnt get that.

Comment: In expo android also behaves the same. In an andoid emulator or actual device, the screen gets resized when the keyboard opens, nothing is hidden underneath the keyboard; this is the behavior I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `<keyboardavoidingview />`. Using this component that screen will push itself up once a textinput is focused. Check https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview